# Converting multiple lines into single line using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line

I've no idea if this is basic or what but I have this data that contains multiple lines (forming a polygon shape). I want to convert those lines (multiple - each with a start and end point) to a single line. I tried dissolve, multipart to single part etc. I cannot use topology since it influences precision. I have zero knowledge of programming.

Comment: When you dissolved, did you check the "unsplit lines" option?

Comment: I checked it in both ways... :) dint work...

Comment: For example, if you had a hexagon made up of six line segments,  what would you like the final product to be?  A single polygon?  Or maybe a single hexagonal polyline with one attribute?

Comment: yeah either a single line or a single polygon (preferable)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [dissolving](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) based off of OBJECTID or FID.  Then use [Feature To Polygon (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000) to convert your polylines to polygons if you wish.  To illustrate, here are some sample lines:

[image]

**Attribute table before dissolve by OBJECTID**

[image]

**Attribute table after dissolve by OBJECTID**

[image]

Comment: where were u @aaron before I added this to bounty... :P well, this is working very well with exceptions like at times minor issues are faced. Once I get done ill b back... :) thx a lot

Comment: yeah it worked out well.... thax a lot @aaron

Comment: Having this same issue and the above solution is not working, no matter which field I dissolve on multiple lines persist

Comment: @jeremythamm Are the polylines all touching?  If not, you have broken geometry and need to fix that before doing the above steps.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, that was the issue, there was a tiny hole between two of the lines.

Answer (score 4):

If your lines are already in the same data layer, then you won't need anything from the toolbox -- just use the Editor, and follow the instructions in "[Merging features in the same layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000007q000000.htm)."

If you have different layers, first [Merge](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000055000000) them into one layer (Data Management | General | Merge), and *then* merge the features together using the Editor.

Comment: Hi @Erica, thanks a lot as it worked well with lil prob... this merge works only for two lines... More then two lines, and the option greys out... Is it possible to apply it to a number of lines....? I would need that as I have a bigger data set... :)

Comment: Hmmm, it should be able to handle three or more into one long line -- which version of Arc are you working with? (I have 10.1, and it works.) Unfortunately, I haven't actually used this very frequently, so I don't know what sort of quirks you may run into like that.

Comment: its 9.3 with me actually... I tried for the whole group first, failed... then I stepped back n moved to 4, failed, 3 failed and when I merged 2 lines it was a success... :)

Comment: this solution is giving precision issues... cant use it for a large number of data sets... :(

Comment: Sorry it wasn't more helpful!

Comment: This is the solution. If you are unable to merge multiple lines on a single layer then there are other problems with either ArcMap or the data itself. Export your layer into a new file geodatabase, run repair features, create a new map document, load this single layer, start editing, select all featured and merge (editor menu)

Comment: @Jakub thx a lot dear... I could do that before u told... :) good help anyways... :) thanks again...

Comment: Shall we tick the 'Preserve Overlapping Segment' option? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in your case, but suggesting to try the option "Convert Multipart Shapes to Single Parts" of "XTools Pro - Extension for ArcGIS"

Comment: tried it... but not much help... @aaron's idea is simpler and effective... :)