# Statistics of two point features between a line feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm using arcgis. My datasets are as follows:

- point features

  - values of passed cars in a specific time
- line features as segments between the points

  - overall it is a street network with stops.

My aim:
I want to add to the line feature attribute table the information of which point features are on each end of the line. Additionally calculating the difference of passing cars between the points.

Can you give me a hint how to do this?

EDIT: Sample Picture
[image]

Comment: A simple screen shot of Points over Lines might help. Need to know if Points are on the Lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) GP tool. Choose for

- target features: streets;
- join features: points;
- Merge rule: `Mean` for the value field  you have in cars point feature class.

This is how it is done:

[image]

After running the tool, you will have a new line feature class which will contain the information on how many cars are located on points as well as the mean value. The sample run result:

[image]

Things do get more complicated if there are multiple line features between the points (in the example I've run, there is only a single feature between the points. You would need either to [merge those lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55213/converting-multiple-lines-into-single-line-using-arcgis-desktop) into single ones and then [split at points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/ways-to-split-a-line-feature.htm) where you have cars (to be able to get the values from cars properly distributed).

If you want to check whether a car point is on either end of a street segment and you won't / can't use Python scripting, you could use the [Feature To Vertices](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) GP tool to get both ends of every street segment and then run [Find Identical](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/find-identical.htm) GP tool to find those that are located on those end points. All of this would involve multiple steps.

You might look at [ModelBuilder](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm) to see if building models is something for you, otherwise learn some primitive [arcpy](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-arcpy-.htm).